# Print footer directly after last row in page

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that I made a code to print the sheet and the data in the sheet is dynamic by another code. I mean the number of rows that will be printed will not be fixed all the time
Is there a way to print the footer directly after the last row of each page as the page sometimes has only 5 rows and at this case the footer is far away from the data .. so I need a way to make the footer near the data in that case? Is that possible?
Note I don't want to include the footer as temporary row and delete that row after the print ..

Here's my try till now

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer, x As Double, lr As Integer
Dim a, y
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    x = .FooterMargin
    For i = 1 To .Pages.Count
        If i = .Pages.Count Then
            'Stop
            'How to set the margin so as to suit the last row of data
            lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("A1:H" & lr).Address
            a = Mid(Sheets("Sheet1").HPageBreaks(1).Location.Address(0, 0), 2, 99) - 1


            y = a - (lr - (a * (.Pages.Count - 1)))

            MsgBox y
            '.FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.78740157480315)
        End If
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut from:=i, To:=i, Preview:=True
        'ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
    Next i
    .FooterMargin = x
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you manipulate the FooterMargin to push the footer text up the sheet?

Comment: That's exactly what I need to do .. but I couldn't do that :)

Comment: Yeah, looks like Margins setting can only be set for all pages.  The only option might be the one you rejected - a temporary row

Comment: Is there a way to change the margin for the last page only to suit the last row .. and then to restore the margin to original position?

Comment: Since you can only set the margins for *all* pages, a temporary change doesn't work, because it would also affect the previous pages and therefore change the amount of pages.

Comment: One rather ugly work around would be to set the print range to exclude the last page, and set footers normally, and print that.  Then set the print range to just the last page and set margins as required,  then print that separately.